# GWT: How do I get a Button widget reference given a FormPanel?

Tags: gwt, formpanel

I'm using GWT 2.4.  I have a reference to a FormPanel, which contains a Button, with id="save."  How do I get a reference to the Button widget given the form panel instance?

Note, that Button is not a direct descendant of formPanel, so "formPanel.getWidget()" will not automatically return a reference to the Button.

Thanks, -

Comment: Can you post code or sample code of what you're meaning?

Answer (score -1):

You can use

`formPanel.getWidget()`,

if you're using `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FormPanel`. It will give you the reference to the widget you've added in the FormPanel.

Comment: I'll edit my queston, but the Button with id="save" is not a direct descendant of Formpanel, so getWidget does not return a reference to it.  Given this, how do I get a reference to the Button widget given only that I know its id and it is a descendant (at some level) of FormPanel?

Comment: This answer is actually incorrect. The `getWidget()` method is inherited from `SimplePanel`, which `FormPanel` extends. Calling `getWidget()` would return the one and only widget in the form (the "container" for the form fields). In the case of my example, it would return `fieldContainer`.

Comment: Hey Chris, SimplePanel allows only one widget to be added into it & so does FormPanel according to http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SimplePanel.html. I've tried running your sample code before posting the answer but I can't get to know that which FormPanel are you using as it gives me `java.lang.IllegalStateException: SimplePanel can only contain one child widget`. Have you run your code before posting it? Or Can you clarify which FormPanel are you using?

Comment: @RAS You may have missed the edit on November 22. Please try running it again.